# ActiveX Controls resize when Excel 2010 file is opened

Tags: excel, activex

I've read plenty all over the interwebs about issues with ActiveX controls resizing themselves when clicked or going to print preview. I am having neither problem.

I am having a problem with ActiveX controls resizing themselves when I open an `XLSM` (or `XLSB` it appears) file in `Excel 2010`. `XLS` files seem to be okay.

Clicking the buttons does not cause any new sizing issues. The issue only appears when opening the file. If I delete all of the controls and remake them, the problem does go away. Does anyone else have this problem and know a way to solve it without having to:

1. Delete the controls and re-create them
2. Add any `VBA` code to the workbook to prevent resizing or save previous size parameters
3. Using `Form` Controls instead of `ActiveX` Controls

Basically I'm looking for an easy fix for this issue that doesn't require me to mass modify many different workbooks that I experience this problem in, if possible.

Comment: So basically, you're asking a question that's flagged as `VBA` without actually wanting any code?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the button > Format Control > Properties > Don't move or size with cells
That should solve the problem

Comment: Normally I would say this is correct when the resizing of controls is because of moving columns or cells, but that is not what is happening. That property is already set to Don't move or size. After really looking at the file closely, I see that it is occurring when the workbook opens and ONLY on the active worksheet, not any other worksheet within the workbook that might have other ActiveX controls on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why VBA should be a problem since you'll generally process the button click with VBA.  I'm answering this question here because it's the most recent request for info on this question and I think I've recently found the simplest method to [had a brain fart and forgot how I solved this problem so edit to correct the record] keep your ActiveX controls from resizing in Excel.  You have to force a redraw.  I do it by manipulating the .Top property in the control's _Click event:

```
'REMOVE FOCUS WHEN ACCELERATOR USED, .TOP MANIPULATION FIXES RESIZE BUG
With cmdSubmit
    .Visible = False
    .Visible = True
    .Top = .Top - 1
    .Top = .Top + 1
End With
```

That keeps the button looking good at all times. I also make the buttons invisible and visible with each click to remove residual focus that remains when users use Accelerator keys to actuate them (TakeFocusOnClick specifically only works with Clicks), which is especially relevant because the ability to build keyboard-enabled solutions is the only reason I stick with ActiveX controls.